# Import statement flow

Tags: python, flask, python-import

**My app layout**

```
my_app
    __init__.py 
    my_app
        __init__.py
        startup
            __init__.py
            create_app.py
            create_users.py
            common_settings.py
        core
            __init__.py
            models.py
            views.py
        errors
            __init__.py
            errors.py
```

**Inner __init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)           # The WSGI compliant web application object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)            # Setup Flask-SQLAlchemy
manager = Manager(app)          # Setup Flask-Script

from my_app.startup.create_app import create_app
create_app()
```

**create_app.py**

```
def create_app(extra_config_settings={}):              

    # Load all blueprints with their manager commands, models and views
    from my_app import core                                                     

    return app
```

**core/__init__.py**

```
# from . import views
```

**views.py**

```
from my_app import app, db
from flask import Flask, request

@app.errorhandler(Error)
def handle_invalid_usage(error):
    response = jsonify(data=error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response
```

I based this code on a tutorial I found. Everything works fine as long as I leave the `__init__.py` in the **core** folder empty.

When I don't, I get a `NameError: name Error is not defined` in my `views.py`. `Error` comes from `errors.py`.

**I have three questions:**

1) Why does this happen only when I leave the `import` statement in **core/__init__.py**.

2)

**create_app.py**

```
app.config.from_envvar('ENV_SETTINGS_FILE')
# Other app.config commands here

from my_app import core

return app
```

What happens when `from my_app import core` runs?

3) Finally when I `return app`, is this to ensure that **Inner __init__.py** file contains the updated `app` object?

Any explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is `Error` defined in `views.py`? It's not imported or anything, so it's little wonder you get a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to build and configure an app with dynamic imports is really bad news and confusing for the reasons you are discovering. A much better and understandable pattern would be a more typical factory:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configure_app(app, config)
    register_db(app)
    add_views(app)
    add_manager(app)

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

But since you're asking, your problem is here:

```
from my_app import app, db
from flask import Flask, request

@app.errorhandler(Error) # Error is not imported
def handle_invalid_usage(error):
    response = jsonify(data=error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response
```

The error occurs because `views.py` is imported, the code compiler comes across `Error` and cannot find a reference to it.

For your second question: `from my_app import core` causes `core.__init.__`  to run, which (presumably) adds the views onto the app object.

Comment: Thanks for that jumbopap. Would you happen to have a link to a repo where this pattern is being used? I think it would be really helpful for me to see.

Comment: I'll write a github gist explaining it.